# How do I count the total occurrences of an attribute from a json dataset?

Tags: python, json

I'm having trouble looping over the entire dataset.

```
import json

yelp_data = []
with open('yelp_reviews_test.json') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        yelp_data.append(json.loads(line))

print(yelp_data[0]['votes']['funny'])
```

This is my code but it only outputs the number of "funny" from one entry. I need the number of "funny" for the entire dataset.

Comment: Can you do it using the `for` loop you already have? What else have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

### Follow-Up Answer

Assuming that the 'funny' key contains an integer, you could try this:

```py
import json

funny_total = 0
with open('yelp_reviews_test.json') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        json_obj = json.loads(line)
        funny_total += json_obj['votes'].get('funny', 0)
```

### Original Answer

You are accessing the first JSON object in the `yelp_data` list with the line:

`print(yelp_data[0]['votes']['funny'])`

`[0]` accesses the first entry in the list.

Instead, you could either access the data as you iterate over the file:

```py
import json

with open('yelp_reviews_test.json') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        json_obj = json.loads(line)
        print(json_obj['votes']['funny'])
```

Or, you could iterate through the list of JSON objects after you have populated the list:

```py
import json

yelp_data = []
with open('yelp_reviews_test.json') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        yelp_data.append(json.loads(line))

for json_obj in yelp_data:
    print(json_obj['votes']['funny'])
```

Comment: How would I sum up the output after then?

Comment: @Ssangkal I have updated my answer. Please try that.